# Java stacks basic movement of characters from expression issue

Tags: java, stack

I can't figure out after spending 4 hours + on getting this pop / push part to work. I have to create my own pop and push which I did and with a basic insert characters to the stack and then display them it works through a driver. But now having to add expressions No matter what I do I can't get rid of the "Cannot find symbol error" or "error: method pop in class charStack cannot be applied to given types."

I tried to change my array to an objects array and I get something similar but nothing is making sense or testing out for what I am trying to do.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
     public class charStack
     {
    
        //class constants
        private final static char ADD = '+';      // Intalizes character for adding
        private final static char SUBTRACT = '-'; // Intalizes character for subtracting
        private final static char MULTIPLY = '*'; // Intalizes character for multipluing
        private final static char DIVIDE = '/';   // Intalizes character for dividing
    
        //class variables
        private int[] stack;  // Intalizes array
        private int stackSize; // Intalizes Size of stack
        private int top;       // Intalizes top position

 public charStack()
     {
        //local constants

        //local variables

        /**************************/

        stackSize = 10;              // Sets size of stack to 10
        stack = new int[stackSize];  // Sets array for stack
        top = 0;                     // Sets top to zero

     }// END constructor

public int calculation(String expr)
      {

         //local constants

         //local variables
         int operand1;                      // Intalizes operation place holder one
         int operand2;                      // Intalizes operation place holder two
         int result;                        // Intalizes result
         String token;                      // Intalizes token
         Scanner pars = new Scanner(expr);  // Intalizes pars of scanner

         /**********************************/

         // Sets result to zero
         result = 0;

         // WHILE there is something in the string
         while (pars.hasNext())
         {

            // Takes the first operand from the string
            token = pars.next();

             // IF operand is valid
             if (isOperator(token))
             {
                // Operand 2 is moved from the stack (Issue 1)
                operand2 = stack.pop();

                // Operand 1 is moved from the stack (Issue 2)
                operand1 = pop(stack);

                // Operation is evaluated and set to result
                result = evaluateSingleOperator(token.charAt(0), operand1, operand2);

                // Returns the value of the given expression
                stack.push = (new Integer(result));
             }

             // ELSE
             else
             {

                // Set next token to top of stack (Issue 3)
                stack[top] = (new Integer(Integer.parseInt(token)));

             }// END IF

         }// END WHILE

         // Return result
         return result;

     }// END Calculation

   public int pop()
   {
      //local constants

      //local variables
      int temp; // Intializes temp character holder

      /**************************/

      // Drops the count of the stack by 1
      top--;

      // Removes element from the top of the stack
      temp = stack[top];

      // Return element removed from top of stack
      return temp;

   }// END pop

  public void push(int num)
  {
     //local constants

     //local variables

     /**************************/

     // Sets top of stack to character
     stack[top] = num;

     // Add one to stack placement
     top++;

  }// END push
```

Comment: Issue 1: You are trying to use `stack.pop()`, but `stack` is declared as `int[]` and not an instance of your class and an int array does not have the method `pop()`.

Comment: Issue 2: You are trying to use `pop(stack)` but you haven't declared any `pop` method that takes a parameter.

Comment: Issue 3: I am not sure what the "issue" is here as I can't follow that from your question. No need to do the `new Integer` part though as `Integer.parseInt(token)` returns an `int` and your `stack` is an `int[]` already.

Comment: You have more issues to come in your code, but those are the ones you highlighted.

Comment: To follow what your saying with Issue 1. If I were to change the 'int[]' to 'Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();' Then that would be creating an instance of my class?

Comment: No. To use an instance of your class, you need to invoke the constructor of your class somewhere. If it is your task to create your own implementation of a stack, it wouldn't make sense to use an exisiting one. But if your task just states that you should implement an algorithm, and you are free how to do this, then you can use an existing Stack from the standard library.

Comment: That said, it seems that the `calculation()` method should not be a member of the stack class. Instead, it should be somewhere else, and just use an instance of your stack implementation.

Comment: We have to create our own implementation of a stack.  So you said I had to invoke the constructor of my class somewhere. I thought that's what the `public charStack();` was. even though I have it not pulling anything form the driver currently.

Comment: @Hulk If I am understanding this correctly then calculation()  would be in a new class and the charStack would just have the methods for pop, push, peek, etc..., isOperator (), and evalutateSingle Operator.  (Driver Program => Evaluate Program => CharStack).

Comment: @Shields92 In your class you have declared the constructor, which is exactly what `public charStack()` is. But you are not using it anywhere and using it within the same class as where it is declared doesn't make much sense here. You should have a separate class to invoke your stack class functions. Instantiation: `charStack stack = new charStack()`. Note: It is best practice to have first character of a class name in Upper case, so your class should really be named `CharStack`.

Comment: And as @Hulk mentioned, your `calculation()` method seems a bit misplaced. It could possible also be misused in your class. Depends a bit on what you are trying to do with it.

Comment: @Shields92 yes, that sounds like a reasonable possible solution.

Comment: DanielBarbarian & Hulk Thank you both! I figure I have to have the driver class point to the evaluation class that contains the calculation () and any other method that's not apart of the pop / push part of the program. I guess overall I was thinking it had to be two classes and was blinded to the pop being separate because instead of using the built in stack I created my own stack class.